# GAE - Google Cloud SQL API do not show any errors but doesn't create table

Tags: api, google-app-engine, google-cloud-sql

I've been trying to use the Cloud SQL API from Google App to import a CSV file to my Cloud SQL database I followed  [this](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/admin-api/v1beta4/instances/import#try-it%0A) , this is the method that does it:

```
def upload_file(cls):
    credentials = GoogleCredentials.get_application_default()

    service = discovery.

build('sqladmin', 'v1beta4', credentials=credentials)

# * Project ID of the project that contains the instance.
project = 'apptest'

# * Cloud SQL instance ID. This does not include the project ID.
instance = 'test'

instances_import_request_body = {
    "importContext": {
        "kind": "sql#importContext",
        "fileType": "csv",
        "uri": "gs://mybucket/test1.csv",
        "database": "test",
        "csvImportOptions": {
            "table": "lote_1",
            "columns": [
                "id",
                "numbers"
            ]
        }
    }
}

request = service.instances().import_(project=project, instance=instance, body=instances_import_request_body)
response = request.execute()

print response
```

Response:

```
{
{u'user': u'dyego.lima@modinify.com', u'selfLink': u'https://www.googleapis.com/sql/v1beta4/projects/apptest/operations/d64dc88e-2395-4833-933f-2e004b5f961a', u'operationType': u'IMPORT', u'targetLink': u'https://www.googleapis.com/sql/v1beta4/projects/apptest/instances/test', u'status': u'PENDING', u'importContext': {u'database': u'test', u'csvImportOptions': {u'columns': [u'id', u'numbers'], u'table': u'lote_1'}, u'uri': u'gs://extraaniversario2016/test1.csv', u'kind': u'sql#importContext'}, u'insertTime': u'2016-10-24T20:59:17.853Z', u'kind': u'sql#operation', u'targetProject': u'apptest', u'name': u'd64dc88e-2395-4833-933f-2e004b5f961a', u'targetId': u'test'}
}
```

My CSV file:

```
id;numbers
1;5
12345654;10
43543543543;2
343546464;8
```

I'm stuck because I don't know if I can fetch the result since it's "PENDING", I googled and tried different things for several hours but I can't figure out what is wrong.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

When you start the import operation, the response will contain an operation ID. You need to call the [operations.get API](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/admin-api/v1beta4/operations/get) with the operation ID to check when the operation is done. When the operation is done, the status will indicate whether it was successful and any errors that happened during the import.

For CSV imports, the destination table must exist before you call the import API.